# Add images to ListBox (c#, windows phone 7)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am developing the Windows Phone 7, I need to add images to ListBox.

I want do it with C# code, not XAML.

I read about it, but everyone uses BitmapImage, which I can't get to work on Windows Phone 7.

I have XAML code:

```
<StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,17">
    <local:MatchDates Adress="http://soccernet.espn.go.com/results/_/league/esp.1/spanish-la-liga?cc=57393" />
</StackPanel>
```

and C# function in my class MatchDates:

```
    void add_items(List<List<string>> code)
    {
        if (code.Count == 0)
            this.Items.Add("no mathes");
        else
        {
            foreach (List<string> temp1 in code)
            {
                foreach (string temp2 in temp1)
                {
                    this.Items.Add(temp2);
                }
                this.Items.Add("---------------------------------");
            }
        }
    }
```

How can I add images in function add_items?

This code:

```
    Uri uri = new Uri("/eng.png", UriKind.Relative);
    BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage(uri);
    Image img = new Image();
    img.Height = 30;
    img.Width = 30;
    img.Source = bitmap;
    this.Items.Add(img);
    this.Items.Add(temp2);
```

Only empty space is presented, How do I add images to ListBox?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the ways I used:

XAML:

```
<ListBox Name="lstView" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
   <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
          <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
             <Image Source="{Binding ImagePath}"></Image>
             <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
      </DataTemplate>
   </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

C#:

```
public class Article
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string ImagePath { get; set; }
}


 Article article1 = new Article() { Name = "name1", ImagePath = "path of image 1" };
 Article article2 = new Article() { Name = "name2", ImagePath = "path of image 2" };

 var articles = new List<Article>();
 articles.Add(article1);
 articles.Add(article2);

 lstView.DataContext = articles;
```

For retrieving articles I use WCF service.

Answer (score 1):

BitmapImage is supported. You have to declare the BitmapImage as ImageSource.

Comment: Can you give me the example of code, please? It's my first project :)

Comment: i used this one in an app: Uri imageUri = new Uri("herecomestheUri", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute); new BitmapImage() { UriSource = imageUri };ImageSource SrcImage = imageUri; this is a very simple example, but the one after my answer is also a good example.

Comment: Can I do something about this:                         Uri uri = new Uri("uri",UriKind.Relative);
                        BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage(uri);
                        Image img = new Image();
                        img.Height = 30;
                        img.Width = 30;
                        img.Source = bitmap;
                        this.Items.Add(img);
?
I suppose that this.Items.Add(img) is wrong