# Loading image from projects files

Tags: image, listbox, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to get png image which is my Resource folder. I tested solution that was written here :[Add images to ListBox (c#, windows phone 7)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9348766/add-images-to-listbox-c-windows-phone-7). For start I wanted to get the same image for every item in my ListBox. But I can't achive that. The picture doesn't show.

It's how my list in xaml look like:

```
<ListBox x:Name="ProductList">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                        <Image Source="{Binding ImagePath}"  Stretch="None"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

This is how I populate Items:

```
List<ImageData1> productsList = new List<ImageData1>();

foreach (ProductItem item in ProductsTable)
{
    if (item.Category == chosenCategory.TrId)
    {
            ImageData1 img = new ImageData1();
            img.Name = item.Name;
            img.ImagePath = new Uri("Resources/img.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
            productsList.Add(img);
    }
}

ProductList.ItemsSource = productsList;
```

Here is my class to hold image data:

```
public class ImageData1
{
    public Uri ImagePath
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Comment: First check if you have data binding errors. Take a look at Output windows during the application load time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting `/` before your image path. Like `/Resources/img.png`. And try to change `UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute` to  `UriKind.Relative`. And make sure your images are added as `Content` (`Build Action` property of image). That way it works for me.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, was that because of slash?

Comment: No it wasn't. UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute also work fine. My image wasn't added as Content. Thank you for help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Probably, You can also use the following assembled code to read the image from the current application.

```
StreamResourceInfo info =Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("Resources/img.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
var bitmap = new BitmapImage();
bitmap.SetSource(info.Stream);
img.Soure = bitmap;
```