# The best way to keep large amount of data on windows phone?

Tags: windows-phone-8, data-storage

I'm making application on Windows Phone, and I need to keep photos in my application. They will be around 1-1,5 GB, but I can't download it while application is starting. I would like to make them built-in in project, but I don't know what will be the best way to do it. I read that I can't write data to SD card on Windows Phone. And I'm using local database to keep my other data that can be downloaded, but there is also space limit. What else can I do?

Comment: You are possibly putting the cart before the horse.  How many customers do you think will download your app from the store when they see it is a jiggabyte?

Comment: @HansPassant This application is not designed for commercial use. So I don't have to care whether people will download it or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just store those files in subfolder (say, `MyImages`) of your project, and assign them a `Content` Build Action (set in file's properties). They can be accessed in runtime via `new BitmapImage(new Uri("/MyImages/img1.jpg", UriKind.Relative));`

And yep, they will not go to the memory card, because apps cannot be installed there. So be careful about device memory limits.

Comment: All right, I seem to answered almost exactly as on your previous question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14628416/loading-image-from-projects-files/14629532). Didn't notice that it's you again. :)

Comment: I didn't think about it that way. Thank you very much for your help once again.:)